# using jTable.setRowHeight(selectedRow, 20) for only selected Row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

hi guys hope you all well today.
my question to day about how to use

```
int selectedRow = jTable.getSelectedRow();
jTable.setRowHeight(selectedRow, 40);
```

for only that selected row.. i want to use that with `KeyEvent.VK_DOWN/VK_UP` or with MousClicked.. any idea guys..

thanks in your advice

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? It's not clear enough to me. What are you trying to achieve? If possible post an image and a [Runnable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Are you trying to make your selected row higher than the rest?

Comment: Are you trying to make your selected row higher than the rest?    yes exatly that is what i want..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `ListSelectionListener`.

Something like:

```
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()
{
    int lastRow = -1;

    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
    {
        if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting())
        {
            if (lastRow != -1)
                table.setRowHeight(lastRow, table.getRowHeight());

            int row =  table.getSelectedRow();
            table.setRowHeight(row, 40);
            lastRow = row;
        }
    }
});
```